# ADB not working in Android studio 3.3.2, Studio prompting cannot find adb

Tags: android, adb, android-studio-3.3

All working fine till last night but today when I updated the sdk to 28.0.2 in Android studio 3.3.2, The ADB stopped working. I have tried everything like using cmd to kill, start and restart the ADB server plus I have uninstalled the platform-tools from SDK manager, even I have changed the value of Android SDK Tools-Path in the register by setting the path of the ADB that is c:/User/user_name/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk. Technically speaking I have tried every thing every solution provided in the Stack Overflow Community. But still it's is not working. Adding that in Task Manager's Process list there is no ADB.exe listed. Cannot understand what to do. Please some one help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the **"Android SDK Location"** setting correct? Which located in **Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings -> Android SDK**.

Comment: There is a warning for white space as I have my user name by mistake kept like that. This white space was there before n the warning also but everything was going smooth. The location is C:\Users\Abhisek Harichandan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk n it's correct. The white space is in between Abhisek _ Harichandan

Comment: same issue here, just updated to 3.3.2 and unable to access the same devices I was able to access before. Any hint about this? SDK path is correct in Android Studio.